# Trying to find early 2000s EDM track, Japanese vocals, breakdancing skeleton

Tags: electronic-music, music-video, techno

I'm trying to track down this song/electronic group (I think short-lived) that I loved in highschool that no one else knew about somehow. Their music had Japanese vocals but I think they were based in the US. Their music was super fast EDM with high-pitched Japanese vocals and they released their songs with really great animated music videos. One featured a breakdancing skeleton and in another there were a bunch of low-res retro 3D vector tanks in a battlezone. Their sound was really arcade video game informed.